# How to configure cleverly org-archive-location in org-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

BACKGROUND: In org-mode, the variable org-archive-location is set to "%s_archive::" by default, so that a file "toto.org" archives into a file "toto.org_archive". I would like it to archive to "toto.ref" instead. I am using org-mode version 7.4 (out of the git server).

I would have thought it to be as simple as

```
(setq org-archive-location 
      `(replace-regexp-in-string ".org" ".ref" %s)
      )
```

But I was pointed out that this was not proper in LISP (plus, it did not work). My final solution is as follow, you should be able to adapt to most clever configurations of org-archive-location:

```
(setq org-archive-location "%s::* ARCHIVES")
(defadvice org-extract-archive-file (after org-to-ref activate)
  (setq ad-return-value
        (replace-regexp-in-string "\\.org" ".ref" ad-return-value)
    )
  )
```

Note that:

1) I voluntarily did not add a $ at the end of ".org" so that it would properly alter "test.org.gpg" into "test.ref.gpg".

2) It seems that one should use the regular expression "\.org" (rather than, say, ".org") (longer explanation below in the answers).

Comment: you're setting the variable to a list consisting of replace-regexp-in-string (a function), ".org", ".ref" and whatever %s is. I assume that what's expected in that variable is some sort of string that represents a format spec. A list that looks like function invocation will not do anything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't define a variable in Emacs such that its value is obtained by running code; variables have simple, static values.

You can achieve the effect you described by advising the function `org-extract-archive-file`, which is the one that generates an archive location from `org-archive-location`:

```
(defadvice org-extract-archive-file (after org-to-ref activate)
  (setq ad-return-value
        (replace-regexp-in-string "\\.org" ".ref" ad-return-value)))
```

This works for me now, but of course the internals of org-mode are subject to change and this solution may not work forever.

Comment: Sean, which version of org-mode do you use (I use version 7.4)?

Comment: Thanks, it works. I am not sure about the \\.org: shouldn't it be a \.org to match exactly ".org"?

Comment: The regex is "\.org", but to express that in a string literal you need to escape the backslash with another backslash.  Otherwise, Emacs interprets "\." as an escaped period, which is the same as an unescaped period.  Try evaluating the string literal "\." with C-M-:, and you'll see it evaluates to ".".

Answer (score 2):

You should not `quote` an expression that you want to evaluate.  Note also that in a regular expression, `.` matches any character.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to set the file, the location (e.g., main heading) in the file, and whether or not to include additional archive information:

```
(let* (
    (org-archive-location "~/todo.org::* TASKS")
    (org-archive-save-context-info nil))

  ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: `#+ARCHIVE: %s.ref::` at the beginning of your org file. 
Read more about it [here](http://orgmode.org/guide/Archiving.html).

Also, other interesting option is to set inside your headtree the following, for instance:

```
* Main Header of tree
:PROPERTIES:
:ARCHIVE: toto.ref:: * Main Header of tree in archive file
:END:
** sub tree of main header and so on
```

The latter I took from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3g8d-IwIT4).